# Conectarse a servicios web con xml y soap

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap

Estoy integrando un web service de una mayorista de viajes en una web. 
Tengo creada una clase con todos los métodos de llamada que necesito y luego las funciones que ejecutarán estos métodos dependiendo de las elecciones del usuario. Hay una llamada que se me resiste.
Tengo que solicitar la disponibilidad para un determinado circuito, fecha, punto de salida  y número de pasajeros por ejemplo (1 habitación  con ocupación de una persona edad 30 años y otra habitación con ocupación 2 personas de 35 y 45 años respectivamente)

Estos datos se han sacado previamente de un formulario.
Esta es el ejemplo de Request soap

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org   soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://localhost:8080/ITRCIRSRV/itinerary">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:availability>
   <arg0>
   <destinyCode>ES</destinyCode>
   <distribution>
   <distributionId>1</distributionId>
   <pax>
   <age>30</age>
   <paxId>1</paxId>
    <pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
   </pax>
   </distribution>
   <distribution>
   <distributionId>2</distributionId>
   <pax>
   <age>35</age>
   <paxId>2</paxId>
   <pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
   </pax>
   <pax>
   <age>35</age>
   <paxId>3</paxId>
   <pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
   </pax>
   </distribution>
   <itineraryCode>PBC1T2</itineraryCode>
   <startDate>03-11-2019</startDate>
   </arg0>
   </ns1:availability>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

El método que tengo creado es el siguiente

```
public function availability($destinyCode = '', $itineraryCode = '', $startDate, $distribution = array(), $nuevaSesion = FALSE, $itineraryType = FALSE)
    {
        if($startDate && $distribution)
            {
            $this->entrada['arg0']['startDate'] = $startDate;
            if($destinyCode) $this->entrada['arg0']['destinyCode']  = $destinyCode;
            if($itineraryCode) $this->entrada['arg0']['itineraryCode']  = $itineraryCode;

foreach($distribution as $h=>$dis)
    {
$this->entrada['arg0']['distribution']['distributionId'] = $h;
                    foreach($dis as $p=>$d)
                            {
                            $this->entrada['arg0']['distribution']['pax']['paxId']= $p;
                            $this->entrada['arg0']['distribution']['pax']['age'] = $d['age'];
                            $this->entrada['arg0']['distribution']['pax']['pickUpPointCode'] = $d['pickUpPointCode'];                                   
                            }                       
                    }
            if($nuevaSesion)
                    {
                            self::setNodoLogin(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $this->entrada['arg0']['sessionId'] = $this->idSesion;
                    }
                    //LLAMADA
                $this->ws = new SoapClient($this->url,$this->entrada);
                //RESPUESTA
                $this->respuesta = $this->ws->availability($this->entrada);
                    self::iniciarRequest();
                //  echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($this->ws->__getLastRequest()) . "\n<br><br>";  //REQUEST Desarrollo

            }
    }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, tengo creada una función que llama al método disponibilidad con los parámetros que necesita

```
$wsi->availability($destinyCode,$itineraryCode,$startDate,$params);
```

$params, es un array que guarda las distribuciones,

$distributionId = 1;  // (este número irá incrementando según el número de distribuciones, tengo un campo oculto de formulario con el número de habitaciones)

$paxId = 1; // (lo mismo irá aumentando según número de pasajeros, también campo oculto de formulario con número de pasajeros en cada tipo de habitación)

$age = 30;  // (edad sacada de formulario)

$pickupPointCode = 'MAD00';  //(punto de salida sacado de formulario)

Tengo puesto este de prueba

```
$params =array (
    'distribution' =>  array (
          'distributionId' => $distributionId,
       'pax' => 
          array (
               'age' => $age,
               'paxId' => $paxId,
               'pickUpPointCode' => $pickupPointCode,
             ),
       ),

);
```

El problema me surge a la hora de obtener más de una distribución, no sé cómo armar el array para que me funcione.

Es decir convertir la siguiente petición  soap en la función anterior.

```
<distribution>
<distributionId>1</distributionId>
<pax>
<age>30</age>
<paxId>1</paxId>
<pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
</pax>
</distribution>
<distribution>
<distributionId>2</distributionId>
<pax>
<age>35</age>
<paxId>2</paxId>
<pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
</pax>
<pax>
<age>35</age>
<paxId>3</paxId>
<pickUpPointCode>MAD00</pickUpPointCode>
</pax>
</distribution>
```

Por favor agradecería ayuda, orientación, porque llevo con esto atascada semanas.

Creo que he dao toda la información detallada, alguna sugerencia?

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: No logro entender cuál es el problema. ¿No puedes mandar un array de parámetros? ¿No sabes como pedir un array de datos? ¿No sabes manejar la respuesta? ¿No sabes enviar la petición? ...

Comment: No se cómo mandar el array de parámetros.

Comment: Revisa [esta rspuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981533/5587982) en la que se indica una forma de construir el array que será pasado al servidor.

Comment: Sí, ese es el formato que tengo que conseguir pero tengo que crearlo con un loop. Si el usuario mete en el formulario 2 habitaciones dobles  con dos personas en cada una de ellas. Tengo que crear un loop que me asocie cada elemento del formulario con los datos del array. No se si me explico. Aquí me pierdo y necesitaría un ejemplo al menos parecido.